# How to integrate $f(x)$?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

I've been asked to integrate $\int{f(x)}^2 dx$ between the ranges of $L$ and $-L$.

I'm stuck! I understand how to integrate a constant or a function as in $x^2$ or something, but the $f(x)$ format is not something I'm familiar with. Please could someone explain this to me and perhaps guide me?

This is not the actual question I'm trying to solve. I think it might help if I put the above in context, so here's the question I'm trying to solve (I'm not asking anyone to do my homework, this isn't homework...):

> Show that for a periodic function, defined over the integral $x=-L$ to $x=L$:
>
> $$\frac1{L} \int_{-L}^L{f(x)}^2 dx = \frac{a_0^2}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n^2 + b_n^2)$$
>
> where $a_0$, $a_n$ and $b_n$ are Fourier coefficients of $f(x)$.

Comment: Crikey! Thanks iostream for the 10,000 spelling mistakes you sorted!

Comment: It is not the matter of spelling correction it is for formatting of maths terms and notation.can you give f(x) so we can help you

Comment: Thanks, I've added the original question, so you can put this in context. Thanks for your help

Comment: again it is not in proper format what is 1/L. in question where $a_0,a_n,b_n$. $\frac{a^2}{2} + E({a^2 + b^2})$ are the value of f(x) or this is answer of integration?

Comment: 1/L is a multiplier for the integral. Also, the integral is between the limits of L and -L. Finally, the E, is the sumation symbol, from n=1 to infinity

Comment: Sorry, edits made to equation

Comment: Do you mean this? $\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^L f(x)^2\ dx = \frac{a_0^2}{2} + E\{a_n^2+ b_n^2\}$

Comment: @Neal YES! Thank you! The E, by the way, is a sum symbol

Comment: @SexySarah in previous comment you said E stand for summation symbol from n=1 to infinite

Comment: yes, the big E symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't know anything about $f$ other than that it's periodic and has Fourier coefficients $a_n,b_n$. This means the exercise is not about integrating a *particular* function, like $x^2$ or $\cos(x)$, it's about integrating a general Fourier series.

So, second, what can we do? All we know is that $f(x)$ is periodic of period $2L$ and has Fourier coefficients. So really the only thing you can do is write down a Fourier expansion of $f$ and integrate its square:
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\cos(2\pi nx/L) + b_n\sin(2\pi nx/L),$$
so 
\begin{align*}f(x)^2 &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\bigg(a_n\cos(2\pi nx/L) + b_n\sin(2\pi nx/L)\bigg)\bigg(a_m\cos(2\pi nx/L) + b_m\sin(2\pi nx/L)\bigg)\\
&=\sum_{n,m}\bigg(\mbox{product of the two factors}\bigg)\\
&= \mbox{etc ...}
\end{align*}
I'll leave the details for you to work out. Don't forget the most important theorem of Calculus II: $$\int_{-1}^1 \cos(2n\pi x)\sin(2m\pi x)\ dx = \delta_{nm} = \begin{cases}0, & n\neq m\\ 1, & n=m.\end{cases}$$

Third, for a general perspective, note that we can regard $f$ as an element of $L^2[-L,L]$, which has an orthonormal basis of integral-frequency cosines and sines. The Fourier coefficients of $f$ are the coordinates of $f$ with respect to this basis. Since the inner product is integration, your integral is just the square of the norm of $f$:
$$\int_{-L}^L f^2\ dx = \|f\|^2_{L^2}.$$
This suggests that, indeed, your integral will evaluate to the sum of the squares of the Fourier coefficients of $f$.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I'm really pleased you brought up the CosASinB=Snm as well actually. In a few textbooks, I've seen that delta nm listed, what does it mean?

Comment: It's a ["Kronecker delta."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta): $\delta_{mn} = \begin{cases}0, & n\neq m\\ 1, & n = m\end{cases}$.

Comment: Thank you so much neal, I really, really appreciate your help. Have a lovely weekend (what's left of it!)